# How to use jnaerator in a sbt project

Tags: java, c++, maven, sbt, jnaerator

I work on a Scala project that uses c++ code, using sbt. Once compiled, this c++ code is imported into Scala through Java code that uses jna.

Now, currently the Java wrapper are manually written, and I like to automatize this. I've found jnaerator that can do that, but I don't know how I should use it in sbt.

I see two general approaches:

1. use command line, such as `java -jar jnaerator ...` but I don't know how to setup such command line task in sbt? Also, I would need to know the typical project structure to follow: where to output the jna generated code?
2. Use jnaerator maven plugin through sbt, if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might take some iteration until we get it do what you need.

For the first approach, here is how you can run custom system command on sbt (you essentially solve this using Scala code). Add the following to your `build.sbt` file:

```
lazy val runJnaerator= taskKey[Unit]("This task generates libraries from native code")

runJnaerator := {
    import sys.process._
    Seq("java" , "-jar", "jnaerator", "..." ).!
}
```

To execute:

```
>sbt runJnaerator
```

Now the question is where do you need these files files to go? Finally, how do you want to invoke everything?

Comment: tx, I'll use that and generate java file in the src/main/java dir for now. Actually, I saw that jnaerate can generate a jar. In could be a good idea to see if I could make that the output of a sbt (subproject) containing my cpp code. This is could then be used as a dep of my java+scala project.

Comment: Both solutions sound pretty good! By the way, SBT has a pretty nice workflow for code generators. Take a look [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html). Let me know if you need any help with that. You can pretty much have your `compile` task generate all the sources for you (no need to invoke separate tasks).